# Highcharts: Dynamically (programmatically) assign the axis name

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I am trying to add programmaticallya string to the x axis, instead than declaring it in the chart creation.

So for example, I have my chart:

```
$.(document).ready(function{) {
    chart=new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        }
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'theYaxis'}
    }
    series: [1,2,3,4]
    });
});
```

Now I want to change the yAxis title, so I create a small function; so it will look like this:

var titleY;

```
function loadme(){

    $.get('names.csv', function(data){
        var lines= data.split('\n');
        titleY=lines[0].split(','[0];
    });
}

$.(document).ready(function{) {
    chart=new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        }
    yAxis: {
        title: { text: titleY}
    }
    series: [1,2,3,4]
    });
    loadme();
});
```

This will result in the title being empty.

I am checking to be sure that the value is correctly retrieved, using console.log, and the value is collected and printed. What is wrong here? I get the same issue if I populate the $.get function with data that I want to add to the series in the chart: the data is never add to the chart, even if it is correctly retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a demo fiddle **to dynamically change y-axis title**. Refer this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/MRxn3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<input type="button" value="Change Y-axis Title to 'My text'" id="my_btn">
```

JS (part of thec code to update the y-axis title on a button click):

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    $('#my_btn').click(function(){
        //alert('hey');
        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            title:{
                text:"My text"
            }
        });
        alert('Y-axis title changed to "My text" !');
    });
```

**Refer [Highcharts 'update' function documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update)**  for further details.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! I will have to try this without the button, and adding the update code inside a function, hopefully it will work :)

Comment: Let me know if you find some problem, I will help you out !

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- use [`axis.setTitle()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setTitle) - good performance, I advice use that solution for setting title
- use [`axis.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) - lower performance, because it recreates whole axis, while first method only changes title

Comment: Thanks Pawel, I am using also the update to add the values to the chart; so the performance impact is not a problem for me; I have to re-draw the whole axis again.

Comment: When setting new data, only extremes on axis are changed. When using `update` axis is removed and added back.